# CorePlot: How to Get a Correct Value After Zoom? How to Get A Correct Scale Number After Zoom?

Tags: iphone, charts, zooming, core-plot

1. How to Get a Correct Value After Zoom?
2. How to Get A Correct Scale Number After Zoom?
3. How to put Yaxis another side like the following photo

[image]

The problem I am having now is I can get correct Y value if touch the Chart, then you can get a correct Y Value, but if i zoom in, the value will become wrong!

I try to use this function to get the scale

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace*)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint
```

But the scale number i get is not correct

Everyone please help!!!

This is the correct Screen Capture:

[image]

and this is the wrong one

[image]

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace*)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint
{
    NSDecimal plotPoint[2]; 
    CPTXYPlotSpace *xySpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space; 
    [xySpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:interactionPoint]; 
    NSLog(@"Dragg Event Scale:  %f",real_scaleValue);
    NSString *showingcontent_testing=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scale Y VAlue $:%f", 
                                      ([[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY]] doubleValue])];

    return YES;
}


// This method is call when user touch & drag on the plot space.

- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{        
    if( ((self.view.frame.size.height- point.y+20)<324)
       &&((self.view.frame.size.height- point.y+20)>22))
    {

        NSDecimal plotPoint[2]; 

        CPTXYPlotSpace *xySpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space; 

        [xySpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:point]; 

        NSLog(@"Dragg Event Scale:  %f",real_scaleValue);

        showingcontent=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price $:%f", 
                        (([[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY]] doubleValue])*real_scaleValue)-13.42623-5.573770-0.163934];

        current_price_show.text=showingcontent;

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:current_price_show];

        CGRect separator_line_frame = separator_line.frame;

        separator_line_frame.origin.y =self.view.frame.size.height- point.y+20; 

        // final y destination

        separator_line.frame = separator_line_frame;

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:separator_line];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having with converting values at different plot scales is a rounding issue. You get the touch point in pixels. There are only a finite number of pixels in any plot range. If you zoom in, you increase the number of pixels between any two given values.

To move the y-axis to the right, reduce the right padding and make sure the hosting view fills the width of the screen.